# Why does my VBA code crash when cycling through workbooks with links?

Tags: excel, vba, crash

The code below is intended to update a specific link (the B2 ref) for all Excel files in a given folder (the B1 ref). There's an additional condition that it will only save the file down if the number of errors is the same before and afterwards.

However, when I run this it crashes Excel without any indication of why:

```
Sub UpdateLinksWS()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim locWS, locWB As String
    Dim wb, ThisWB As Workbook
    Dim oFSO, oFolder, oFiles, oFile As Object
    Dim noErrors, i, j As Integer
    Dim Links As Variant

    'Access the file location with VBA objects
    locWS = Worksheets("Sheet").Range("B1").Value
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(locWS)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files
    i = 0
    Set ThisWB = ThisWorkbook

    'For each file in the path ...
    For Each oFile In oFiles
        'Set the pathname
        locWB = locWS & oFile.Name
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(locWB)

        'Counts the number of errors in the workbook before updates
        noErrors = ErrorCount(wb)

        'Update links and calculate workbook - first checking the link to update or update all links
        If ThisWB.Worksheets("Sheet").Range("B2").Value = "" Then
            wb.UpdateLink Type:=xlExcelLinks
        Else
            'Check if the sheet is actually there
            Links = wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks) 'getLinks(wb)
            If Links <> Empty Then
                For j = 1 To UBound(Links)
                    If Links(j) = ThisWB.Worksheets("Sheet").Range("B2").Value Then
                        wb.UpdateLink Name:=Worksheets("Sheet").Range("B2").Value, Type:=xlExcelLinks
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        End If
        Application.CalculateFull


        'If there's a different number of errors after the updates, close, list the workbook in Errors and don't save, otherwise save
        If ErrorCount(wb) = noErrors Then
        'Exit and save the changes
            Workbooks(oFile.Name).Close SaveChanges:=True
        Else
            Worksheets("Errors").Cells(2 + i, 2).Value = wb.Name
            Workbooks(oFile.Name).Close SaveChanges:=False
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Function ErrorCount(ByVal wb As Workbook) As Integer
    Dim nbErrors As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    nbErrors = 0

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        On Error GoTo NoErrs
        nbErrors = nbErrors + ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Count
    Next

    ErrorCount = nbErrors

NoErrs:
    Resume Next

End Function
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through code with F8?

Comment: Can you comment out `Application.CalculateFull` and run it again? I know this will make the macro not do what you intend, but they could be a pain point on your mem/cpu and this could help you test to rule that out as a possibility. If you try to move forward while excel is "freezing" then it may crash.

Comment: Thanks. I stepped through the code and it works fine for the first file it's fed in the folder. It then crashes when it tries to open the second file, i.e. at the "Set wb = open..." line. This file doesn't actually open up independently so it must have been corrupted when I ran my code. This helps me a great deal, however, it's worrying that the file, which previously worked fine, is now corrupted! Any thoughts?

Comment: @AndrewWhelan Something to note - your declarations are not doing what you intend. When you write `Dim locWS, locWB As String`, this is declaring `locWS` as a `Variant`, and `locWB` as a `String`. You need to fully write out these lines like `Dim locWS as String, locWB As String`.

Comment: You should also fully qualify your `Worksheets()` lines, especially since you're navigating through multiple workbooks.

Comment: Thanks, I've made these edits. The programme is now cycling through correctly until it hits a sheet that actually has links. When this happens, it gives a type mismatch error for the comparison of "If Links <> Empty Then" ...

Comment: I also replaced this comparison with "Not IsEmpty(Links)" - seems to have done the trick. However, my final issue is in the case where you update all the links in a workbook and it cannot find the path for a given link (i.e. if a file has moved) - in this case, is there a way of telling the computer to "cancel"?